# How can I declare and add parameters to an Acumatica PXDataFieldParam object?

Tags: acumatica

I'm using the Acumatica PXDatabase.Update method to update records in an Acumatica instance.  The code I have is as follows, updating two fields and using another two as restrictors:

```
PXDatabase.Update<xTACProjectTask>(new PXDataFieldAssign<xTACProjectTask.dueDate>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["Due Date"]].Value.ToString())
                                                  , new PXDataFieldAssign<xTACProjectTask.startDate>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["Start Date"]].Value.ToString())
                                                  , new PXDataFieldRestrict<xTACProjectTask.projectID>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["TAC Project ID"]].Value.ToString())
                                                  , new PXDataFieldRestrict<xTACProjectTask.taskCD>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["TAC Task ID"]].Value.ToString()));
```

The PXDatabase.Update command uses a PXDataFieldParam array that contains the PXDataFieldAssign and PXDataFieldRestrict parameters, and the example above creates new instances of those inside the PXDatabase.Update method - but I'd like to find a way to declare the PXDataFieldParam object first and then conditionally add the PXDataFieldAssign objects to it, and finally passing that PXDataFieldParam array to the method.

I'd like to declare it something like this, but I can't seem to find the proper way:

```
PXDataFieldParam[] pfp = **????**;
PXDataFieldParam pf;

pf = new PXDataFieldAssign<xTACProjectTask.dueDate>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["Due Date"]].Value.ToString());
pfp.Append(pf);
pf = new PXDataFieldAssign<xTACProjectTask.startDate>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["Start Date"]].Value.ToString());
pfp.Append(pf);
pf = new PXDataFieldRestrict<xTACProjectTask.projectID>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["TAC Project ID"]].Value.ToString());
pfp.Append(pf);
pf = new PXDataFieldRestrict<xTACProjectTask.taskCD>(tmpRow.Cells[indexMap["TAC Task ID"]].Value.ToString());
pfp.Append(pf);

PXDatabase.Update<xTACProjectTask>(pfp);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining an array of PXDataFieldParam why don't you define a List and then use the method .ToArray() when calling the PXDatabase.Update method.

```
PXDataFieldParam pf = null;
List<PXDataFieldParam> dbParams = new List<PXDataFieldParam>();
pf = new PXDataFieldAssign<SOLine.orderDate>(Accessinfo.BusinessDate);
dbParams.Add(pf);

PXDatabase.Update<SOLine>(dbParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but without the .ToArray() call.  The Update command was complaining that it had to have a PXDataFieldParam object.  I'll give that a try and see if it works...  Thanks.